# How to modify .INI file with using sharpconfig?

Tags: vb.net, ini

I am using [sharpconfig](https://sharpconfig.codeplex.com/) for Load my .INI file. i got success in reading ini file and its very user friendly.

```
 Dim config As New SharpConfig.Configuration
 config = SharpConfig.Configuration.Load("D:\Myini.ini")
```

Now i want to replace particular word of .ini file. SharpConfig showing that its also providing the .INI file modify functionality but i can not able to find how i can modify my file with [sharpconfig](https://sharpconfig.codeplex.com/)

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an `INI` file that looks like this:

```
[MySection]
MySetting = 123
```

You read it with `SharpConfig.Configuration.Load`:

```
Dim yourpath = "c:\WhatEver.ini"
Dim config = SharpConfig.Configuration.Load(yourpath)
Console.WriteLine(config("MySection")("MySetting").Value)
```

This code will print

> 123

Now, to change the INI file, simply assign a new value and save it like:

```
config("MySection")("MySetting").Value = "Foobar"
config.Save(yourpath)
```

The INI file will now look like this:

```
[MySection]
MySetting = Foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

You already refered to the codeplex page and there you can even find a a test app that shows how to do stuff with it: [TestApp](https://sharpconfig.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TestApp/Program.cs)

If you have the Category and the Setting you can get/set the value of the Setting with .Value

In the Sourcecode of SharpConfig it is easy readable what can be accessed. I'm a VB guy myself but it should be no problem to read the c# stuff >> [Settings](https://sharpconfig.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SharpConfig/Setting.cs)

Comment: sorry if i am mistaken but there is no method found to modify existing .ini file. these all methods for reading file in different manner. Do you have any idea about this?